# Searching for a question

Tags: discussion, search

I entered the following into the search box and came up empty: \lim_{n\to\infty}(1+\frac xn)^n

I'd like to know whether someone has posted this question: How does one prove that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac xn\right)^n = e^x\text{ ?}
$$

So two questions: (1) How to search for that?; and (2) Is it there?

Comment: [Here's one](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/358830).  (Found via Google, rather than this site's search engine.)

Comment: [Here's something similar](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/115863/lim-n-rightarrow-infty1-fracrnn-is-equal-to-er), also found using Google.

Comment: [Here](http://www.google.com/search?q=%5Clim_%7Bn%5Cto%5Cinfty%7D(1%2B%5Cfrac%20xn)%5En%20+site%3Amath.stackexchange.com) are the results from Google for that search restricted to math.stackexchange.com. Of course, there are many ways how to write that expression; so it is possible to experiment and try different similar searches.

Answer (score 3):

I've found six posts on this topic, listed [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/11492/43351).

These were found by e.g. looking through related posts; I've also searched for things like:

```
[limit] "\frac" is:q
```

with obvious changes. I didn't really use Google to browse the site this time. But using

```
site:math.stackexchange.com
```

in your Google query limits the search to MSE, which is quite useful.

Answer (score 3):

Try to use Approach0.xyz:

https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Clim_%7Bn%5Cto%5Cinfty%7D%5Cleft(1%2B%5Cfrac%7Bx%7D%7Bn%7D%5Cright)%5En%3D%3F%24&p=1